# Dependencies in Dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I came across this example [link](https://adityaladwa.wordpress.com/2016/05/09/dagger-2-with-retrofit-and-okhttp-and-gson/).
After creating the project I came across this error

```
Error:(18, 10) error: android.app.Application cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
android.app.Application is injected at
com.app.series.dagger.modules.NetworkModule.provideHttpCache(application)
okhttp3.Cache is injected at
com.app.series.dagger.modules.NetworkModule.provideOkhttpClient(cache)
okhttp3.OkHttpClient is injected at
com.app.series.dagger.modules.NetworkModule.provideRetrofit(…, okHttpClient)
retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at
com.app.series.activities.MainActivity.retrofit
com.app.series.activities.MainActivity is injected at
com.app.series.dagger.components.NetComponent.inject(activity)
```

Also I have an error related to DaggerNetComponent that it cannot be resolved but from reading online I think it might me because of the first error

From what I understand it seems to be something with passing activity instead of application or vice versa. I tried for many hours to understand from where this issue comes but I don't see it.

This is my code so far

AppModule

```
@Module
public class AppModule
{
    SeriesApplication mApplication;

    public AppModule(SeriesApplication mApplication) {
        this.mApplication = mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SeriesApplication provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }
}
```

SeriesApplication

```
public class SeriesApplication extends Application
{
    private NetComponent mNetComponent;

    private static SeriesApplication instance;
    public static SeriesApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    public static void setInstance(SeriesApplication instance) {
        SeriesApplication.instance = instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setInstance(this);
        mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .netModule(new NetworkModule("http://www.jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"))
                .build();
    }

    public NetComponent getNetComponent() {
        return mNetComponent;
    }
}
```

NetComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

NetworkModule

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {
    String mBaseUrl;

    public NetworkModule(String mBaseUrl) {
        this.mBaseUrl = mBaseUrl;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Cache provideHttpCache(Application application) {
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
        Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
        return cache;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient(Cache cache) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.cache(cache);
        return client.build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ((SeriesApplication) getApplication()).getNetComponent().inject(this);



        //Create a retrofit call object
        Call<List<Series>> posts = retrofit.create(Restapi.class).getPosts();

        //Enque the call
        posts.enqueue(new Callback<List<Series>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Series>> call, Response<List<Series>> response) {
                //Set the response to the textview
//                textView.setText(response.body().get(0).getBody());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Series>> call, Throwable t) {
                //Set the error to the textview
//                textView.setText(t.toString());
            }
        });
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11-rc2'
        annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11-rc2'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.1'
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

        //OkHttp
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.7.0'

    }
```

I appreciate any help at this point, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With following piece of code:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Cache provideHttpCache(Application application) {
        ...
    }
```

you tell dagger, that *"whenever I ask you to provide a `Cache`, use `Application` in order to build the `Cache`"*.

But you haven't specified how dagger should acquire an instance of `Application`.
Following provider method returns a completely other object:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SeriesApplication provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }
```

It returns an instance of `SeriesApplication`.
Instead, change the return type to `Application`.

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }
```

Now dagger won't be confused.

Answer (score 1):

In `NetworkModule` you provide `Application`, not `SeriesApplication`

From

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Cache provideHttpCache(Application application) {
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
    return cache;
}
```

to

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Cache provideHttpCache(SeriesApplication application) {
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
    return cache;
}
```